# Unit Testing MVC 4 RedirectToAction

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to unit test the redirection of my controller in MVC 4 .Net 4.5. Here is an example:

```cs
    [TestMethod]
    public void Register_PassValidModel_RedirectToHomeIndexShouldBeTrue()
    {
        //Arrange
        var registerModel = new RegisterModel
        {
            Email = "validEmailAddress@domain.com",
            Password = "password"
        };

        //Assign
        var result = _controller.Register(registerModel) as RedirectToRouteResult;

        //Assert
        result.RouteValues["Action"].ShouldBeEqual("Index");
        result.RouteValues["Controller"].ShouldBeEqual("Home");
    }
```

Here is the controller:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userToRegister = new User { Email = model.Email, Password = model.Password };
            var service = new UserService(_userRepository);

            User user = service.RegisterUser(userToRegister);

            if (user.UserErrorMessages.Count != 0)
            {
                user.UserErrorMessages.ForEach(x => ModelState.AddModelError("", x));
                return View(model);
            }

            SetCookie(model.Email);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

The issue the variable `result` in the Unit Test is `null`. I found this code from someone who was working on a MVC 2 project and it seemed to work for him. Has something changed with MVC 4?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure action actually returns RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")? There should be some logic in the Register action. If it returns any other kind of result and you are trying to make it as RedirectToRouteResult than you will get null.

Comment: I got a RedirectToRouteResult object back when I tried. Are you sure your controller looks just like that?

Comment: I guess you may be getting a ViewResult

Answer (score 37):

Try this one hope it will useful for you

```
 var result= (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Register(registrModel);

           result.RouteValues["action"].Equals("Index");
           result.RouteValues["controller"].Equals("Home");

           Assert.AreEqual("Index", action.RouteValues["action"]);
           Assert.AreEqual("Home", action.RouteValues["controller"]);
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  Also a duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601972/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-a-redirecttoaction

Comment: Worked for me. but had to change the Assert.AreEqual("Index", action.RouteValues["action"]); to Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]); - and left out result.RouteValues["action"].Equals("Index");